# Jquery/ajax/php load data into textfield after clicking checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

How do i load data into textfields after clicking a checkbox & after doing it, i need to disable that textbox, but again as i uncheck it, need to remove that data & make the textbox enable to manually enter data. I tried this code,i'm new to jquery/ajax, can't figure out how to solve this problem.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#chk').click(function(){
     if($(this).is(":checked"))
       $("#txtaddress").removeAttr("disabled");
    else
      $("#txtaddress").attr("disabled" , "disabled");
         // here, i don't know how do i assign $row['address'] to txtaddress by
         // using php mysql 
    });
   });
 </script>

      <!-this is my html code-->
      <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk" name="chk">Same as home address?
        <input id="txtaddress" name="txtaddress"  disabled type="text">
       </form>
```

Comment: For starters, `.atte` should be `.attr`. Then on the next line do `$('#txtaddress").val('<?php echo $row[address];?>');`

Comment: `i need to disable that checkbox, but again as i uncheck it,` - how can you click disabled checkbox to make it uncheck again? its NOT possible

Comment: I think he means disable the text input when the checkbox is checked, at least, I think.

Comment: @JamieTaylor: sorry,it was textbox, i edited.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#chk').click(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked"))
                 $("#txtaddress").val(""); //reset the textbox
                $("#txtaddress").removeAttr("disabled");

            else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: destinationUrl, // your url
                    success: function (data) { // your data ie $row['address'] from your php script
                        $("#txtaddress").val(data); //set the value
                        $("#txtaddress").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
                    }
                });
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

From your `php` script you can `echo` `$row['address']`, so the data in success function can be put into textbox in `ajax`

Answer (score 0):

javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#chk').click(function(){
var txt =   $("#txtaddress");
 ($(this).is(":checked")) ? txt.attr("disabled" , true) :  txt.attr("disabled" , false);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what u meant.. Hope this might help... :)

```
    $('#chk').click(function(){
           if(! $(this).is(":checked")){
               $("#txtaddress").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#txtaddress").val('');
           }
           else{
               $.ajax( {
                url: "get_row_details",
                type: "POST", //or may be "GET" as you wish
                data: 'username='+name, // Incase u want to send any data
               success: function(data) {
                   $("#txtaddress").val(data); //Here the data will be present in the input field that is obtained from the php file
               }
               });
               $("#txtaddress").attr("disabled" , "disabled");
           }
        });
```

From the php file `echo` the desired `$row['address']`.This `value` will be obtained at the `success` of the `ajax function`